# JabRef online help not working

Tags: jabref

It seems last version(s) of JabRef  installs help no more. Instead, in version 3.4, there's only a link to an `online help` which doesn't work. Does any one know where the help/manual has gone?

Comment: So you're talking about http://help.jabref.org/ (http://www.jabref.org/ > Help > Documentation)?

Comment: @Werner: Exactly.

Comment: There is [JabRef Help](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/Contents.php) on SourceForge, but it has a reference date of August 10, 2014. Based on the [Openhub JabRef links](https://www.openhub.net/p/jabref/links) there is another [JabRef Wiki](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/wiki)...

Comment: JabRef has migrated from SourceForge to JabRef.ord and github for development versions. n At the time, JabRef Help was installed with the program. It was some sort of manual for JabRef, and I looked at it now and then when in doubt. Since then, JabRef changed to the 3.x series, and I could only find a FAQ.

Comment: I see the reason for the post but this really is OT.

Comment: http://texnique.fr/osqa/questions/3204/template-these-latex-en-francais that is you, right? I wanted to upvote, but i need at least 15 rep. I guess this will never happen, as my french is really really rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [there have been DNS issues with the help page of JabRef](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/1509), which have just been addressed. Since DNS takes some time to update, please re-check in one or two days.

The version of the help/manual that was installed with JabRef is gone (from version 3.1 onwards I think). The reason for this was that the old help was extremely difficult to update and maintain, especially the localized version. Many of the people doing the localizations do not have programming knowledge, which makes an update of the help impossible. For this reason we decided to move to an online help that is written in markdown and that is separate from the actual source code of JabRef. However, the old manual has been migrated to the online version (as far as it was still valid, and some parts of it were not). So, as soon as DNS is updated, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think there should be an installed manual in English, as one doesn't always have an  Internet connection.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. The web page has the benefit that it might be more up-to-date than a local version. But it shouldn't be a problem technically to ship the webpage together with the software. Currently it is simply a problem of manpower. We have many bugs and feature requests and few people to implement them. Since help is a sort of addon functionality, it does not receive as much attention as it should. If the local help is important for you, you could file a feature request on github and motivate it a little.